# java jsch -executing multiple unix commands

Tags: jsch

`Channel channel=session.openChannel("exec"); 
      ((ChannelExec)channel).setCommand("cd ../ && pwd && ls");
      channel.connect();
      channel.run();`

Here how can i  use the above code if my commands are from command line arguments or if they are stored in variable like cmd1 ,cmd2 etc 
i tried

`((ChannelExec)channel).setCommand("cmd1 && cmd2 && cmd3");`

variable substitution is not happening. Please help me on  this

Thanks,
Prashanth

Answer (score 0):

The variables need to be specified outside of the `String` itself rather than being part of a `String`

```
((ChannelExec)channel).setCommand(cmd1 + " && " + cmd2 " + " && " + cmd3);
```

Comment: ok the above syntax is working fine. But if iam executing some commad in sudo mode iam facing issues: the synta i used is  `((ChannelExec) channel).setCommand(sudoformat+Cmd);` where sudoformat is sudo -S -u 'ims' -H -i

Comment: What issues? seems you need a space between those 2 commands `sudoformat + " " + Cmd`

Comment: iam trying this `((ChannelExec) channel).setCommand(sudoformat+Cmd2+"&&"+Cmd2+"&&"+Cmd3);` where sudoformat="sudo -S -u' '" and Cmd2="cd /home/xxx/xxx/" and Cmd="pwd" .the error is sudo: "cd: command not found".cd is notworking for sudo . also apart from cd , other commands are working but Cmd2 and Cmd3 are not getting executed in sudo mode.

Comment: PLease can any one help with my above query